# display table using display tab library

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

I am using displaytag library to display table.

http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/

I want when a  sortable column is clicked by a user ....... table will be displayed ajax way.

I don't find any documentation on AJAX  call in this tag library.

how do I do a ajax call in this tag library ?

Can you please post any reference to this ?

Comment: please post Ajax implementation.  I want when a user clicks on a sortable column Ajax  call will be called and content will be fetched asynchonously.  Can you please post a reference to this for this tag library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is not natively supported by displaytag.

2 minutes of googling led me to http://ajaxtags.sourceforge.net/ and http://kevin.mudrick.com/2009/11/23/ajax-loading-sorting-and-paginating-of-displaytag-tables/

Comment: ..I am aware of Ajax tags ...but  I am already  using  display tags ..do you have any work around in display tags ajax?

Comment: AjaxTags is precisely a tag that wraps the core displaytag tag, and ajaxifies it. The workaround is to use AjaxTags. The code displaytag tag doesn't support AJAX natively. Read http://ajaxtags.sourceforge.net/usage.html#ajax:displayTag

Comment: @JB  There is no installer in this link http://ajaxtags.sourceforge.net/install.html  ...where from you download this tag ?